Did Tolkien address in any of his letters or later texts the last fate of the Elf-Fathers?
As is well known, the first Elves awoke in Cuiviénen, in the extreme east of Middle-earth, several thousand years before the main events of the war between the Elves and Morgoth narrated in the Silmarilion that take place at the end of the First Age.
We know the fate of many elves born in Cuiviénen before the Sundering of the Elves. For example, Cirdan, Finwë and Elu Thingol.
But none of them was one of the “Elf-Fathers” that Tolkien glosses in his late writings: Imin, Tata and Enel. Since the elves are immortal, these elves must still be alive at the end of the 1st Age, or into the Second and Third Ages.
They may have remained in Middle-earth, as Avari, or they may have ended up in the Blessed Realm. They may have died, but then it is foreseeable that they will have been  re-embodied in Aman. They may also have faded, as is likely to happen with elves who become too attached to Middle-earth. I don´t think that there are more than these three posible fates.
We can deduce that Imin is in Valinor because he is one of the Vanyar and we know that all the Vanyar answered the calls of the Valar.
Did Tolkien write anything about the fate of the other two, or of their first companions and spouses in the Waters of Awakening?
